# How to center canvas in the middle of the screen

Tags: canvas, center

How can I center my canvas? I already tried the command < center> but then the left top corner is centered but I want that my middle of my canvas is the center.

Here's the canvas that I want to center: http://www.inserttalent.nl/~gm15561/project_1.2/periode2.html

I use html5 Kineticjs and javascript.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With plain CSS.

Try

```
Canvas {

    Width: 300px;
    Margin: 0 auto;
    Vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question right, you can put:

```
#myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    background-color:#CFF;
    position:absolute;
    left:100px; // go messing with the value until it's centered.
}
```

or

```
#myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    background-color:#CFF;
    position:center;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

With CSS. Try,

```
canvas {

   border: 1px solid #000000;
   position:        relative;
   left:               500px; (Play with this # to position horizontally)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
//Canvas stuff
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id= "canvas"  width=30px; height=30px; style='display: block;margin: auto;' ></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```